# fdisk -l + how to read output

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, fdisk

what is the meaning of "*" from fdisk -l command , regarding sda1 ?

```
fdisk -l | grep /dev | grep "*"
/dev/sda1   *           1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     1050623      524288   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc1   *        2048     1050623      524288   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

is it mean that sda1 was installed in the past with linux OS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disk `/dev/sda` uses the [GPT partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). `fdisk` has limited support for that scheme; you may want to use [`gdisk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/gdisk.8.html) or [`parted`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/parted.8.html) which have full support for GPT partition tables.

On GPT partitioned disks, the disk management tools create a *protective MBR* partition table, which is intended to provide some modicum of protection against damage which may be done by disk management tools which don't understand GPT. The protective MBR contains one single partition of type `ee`, which covers the entire disk, or as much of the disk as possible (MBR partitions cannot be larger than 2 TB).

So what you are seeing on `/dev/sda` is the fake partition in a protective MBR. Use `sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print free` to list the GPT partition table.

Comment: just more one note - so I am understand that I can use this disk for DB ( I intend to create ext3 FS on this disk ) is it ok?

Comment: @salom: Examine the disk, determine whether it holds data which you want, then use it as you want. The partition shown in the question is _not_ the real partition on disk. Use a GPT-aware tool to see the real partitions.